# ActiveRecord objects - querying retrieved records

Tags: ruby, activerecord

This is puzzling me.

I have:

```
person = Person.find_or_create_by(user_id: some_id)
previous_person = Person.where('user_id < ?' some_id).limit(1).order('user_id desc')
binding.pry
```

In pry I do:

```
person.user_id
=> 12

previous_person.user_id
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Person:0x007fdd24d635b8>
```

Why can't I access the user_id for previous_person?

(apologies for any typos - wasn't a direct copy and paste)

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to do it. Question corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Doh. I can' believe I fell for this again!

Of course, Person.where returns an array.

The correct code is `previous_person = Person.where('user_id < ?' some_id).order('user_id desc').first`

Comment: ActiveRecord effectively translates .first to .limit, so you don't need both.

Comment: Does `limit` do anything without arguments?

Comment: `Person.where` does *not* return an Array, it returns an ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: @rxgx: You can usually add a `to_sql` call to the chain if you want to see what the various components are doing.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Correct, for the purposes of this question, though, array is close enough.

Comment: @SnowCrash Not really, Array doesn't respond to `order`, after all.